# Database [users] not configured

Tags: laravel, user-registration, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm using Cartalyst Sentinel to register a user. Everything works fine (form, validation, etc) but when I send a valid user information, this error Pops out.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhYS5.jpg
database.php : http://laravel.io/bin/DeG7n

Comment: Did you ever solve this?